# ansible filter specific line stdout_line

Tags: ansible

I have below playbook that generates `stdout_lines` which has multi line output.

```yaml
    - name: Execute
      command: cbstats db-host:db-port -u User -p Password -b orders all
      register: count

    - name: Print
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      with_items: "{{ count.stdout_lines }}"
```

Output of stdout_lines:

```
TASK [Print] **************************************************************************************************ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        " accepting_conns:                                       1",
        " auth_cmds:                                             0",
        " auth_errors:                                           0",
        " bytes:                                                 3756475864",
        " bytes_read:                                            2015848580",
        " bytes_subdoc_lookup_extracted:                         0",
```

Now I want to get only `bytes` from `stdout_lines`. Any idea how this can be achieved ?

Comment: can't you simply add the `grep bytes` to your command?

Comment: I've edited my answer for a more complete one.

Answer (score 2):

Your command outputs yaml. You can simply load that yaml and address the key your looking for. Using your above example data, the following task

```yaml
- name: debug bytes from output
  debug:
    var: (count.stdout | from_yaml).bytes
```

Gives:

```
TASK [debug bytes from output] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "(count.stdout | from_yaml).bytes": "3756475864"
}
```

Comment: +1, Right, since the Couchbase CLI tool `cbstats` which provides Data Service statistics for a host can simply output in JSON format if specifying with `-j`.

Answer (score 1):

It's very unclear to what you exactly want, since there are 3 values with `bytes` in the output.
As I said in the comments, you can already solve this by adding `| grep bytes` to your command.

To achieve what you want by using Ansible, you can use the `search_regex` filter.

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ count.stdout | regex_search('.*bytes:.*')  }}"
```

This should give:

```yaml
        " bytes:                                                 3756475864",
```

If you want to go the extra mile, and make the value of bytes workable in Ansible as an integer, you can do the following:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    the_bytes_int: >-
      {{ 
          me.stdout_lines[3].split(':')[1] |
          trim |
          replace('"','') |
          replace(',','') |
          int 
      }}
```

`the_bytes_int` is now an integer w value: `3756475864`.
But again, it's easier to solve this on the command line instead of Ansible.

Comment: Is there any way to split and trim along with regex_search itself ?